# Loopback include filter not working for User model

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a Car model with the following relation:

```
 ...
 "relations": { 
    "belongsToUser": { 
      "type": "belongsTo", 
      "model": "MyUser", 
      "foreignKey": "" 
    },
   "shop": {
     "type": "belongsTo",
     "model": "Shop",
     "foreignKey": ""
   }
 }
```

Now, if I try this request:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/cars?filter={"include": ["belongsToUser"]}
```

It doesn't include the user related to the cars.

If I try this request:

```
`http://localhost:5000/api/cars?filter={"include": ["shop"]}`
```

It does return the shop correctly. What's wrong with the user inclusion?

Comment: Can you provide your user model?

Comment: Have you found any solutions? I'm experiencing the same problem

Comment: @danielrvt Could you provide both MyUser and Shop model definition?